# How to add a money value to a Button in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, currency, pos

I am making a Point of Sale (order taking) system. I would like to know how to assign a value to a button in c# in Winforms. For example, when you press the "meat lovers pizza" button, it appears in a Listbox with the name of the food item on the button and the price of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *just add* pizza name and price to ListBox all you need is to handle button click (create new handler by double clicking a button in form designer).

```
private void PizzaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyListBox.Items.Add("Meat Lovers Pizza - $12");
}
```

But I guess you want to store orders somehow. One simple idea is to create a pizza class and store all ordered pizzas in some property.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<Pizza> Pizzas { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PizzaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyListBox.Items.Add("Meat Lovers Pizza - $12");
            Pizzas.Add(new Pizza()
            {
                Name = "Meat Lovers Pizza",
                Price = 12
            });
        }
    }

    public class Pizza
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
```

This should get you started. You can later generate some kind of orders summary from that list of pizzas. Maybe create a list of available pizzas etc. Good luck.